# Why doesn't my method work with letter ENUMS?

Tags: java, keyboard

I'm attempting to write a dynamic keybind system for a java game. It mostly works, except for one huge problem: characters like `a`, `b` ,`c` don't work. Only characters like `~`, `&`, `$` work.

I call the method with `KeyFinder lookup = KeyFinder.lookup(keyChar);`

Here is my current code file, sorry if this is really long.

## KeyFinder.java

```
public enum KeyFinder {
    A(Keyboard.KEY_A, "a", "A"),
    B(Keyboard.KEY_B, "b", "B"),
    C(Keyboard.KEY_C, "c", "C"),
    D(Keyboard.KEY_D, "d", "D"),
    E(Keyboard.KEY_E, "e", "E"),
    F(Keyboard.KEY_F, "f", "F"),
    G(Keyboard.KEY_G, "g", "G"),
    H(Keyboard.KEY_H, "h", "H"),
    I(Keyboard.KEY_I, "i", "I"),
    J(Keyboard.KEY_J, "j", "J"),
    K(Keyboard.KEY_K, "k", "K"),
    L(Keyboard.KEY_L, "l", "L"),
    M(Keyboard.KEY_M, "m", "M"),
    N(Keyboard.KEY_N, "n", "N"),
    O(Keyboard.KEY_O, "o", "O"),
    P(Keyboard.KEY_P, "p", "P"),
    Q(Keyboard.KEY_Q, "q", "Q"),
    R(Keyboard.KEY_R, "r", "R"),
    S(Keyboard.KEY_S, "s", "S"),
    T(Keyboard.KEY_T, "t", "T"),
    U(Keyboard.KEY_U, "u", "U"),
    V(Keyboard.KEY_V, "v", "V"),
    W(Keyboard.KEY_W, "w", "W"),
    X(Keyboard.KEY_X, "x", "X"),
    Y(Keyboard.KEY_Y, "y", "Y"),
    Z(Keyboard.KEY_Z, "z", "Z"),
    TILDE(Keyboard.KEY_GRAVE, "~", "`"),
    TAB(Keyboard.KEY_TAB, "tab"),
    F1(Keyboard.KEY_F1, "F1"),
    F2(Keyboard.KEY_F2, "F2"),
    F3(Keyboard.KEY_F3, "F3"),
    F4(Keyboard.KEY_F4, "F4"),
    F5(Keyboard.KEY_F5, "F5"),
    F6(Keyboard.KEY_F6, "F6"),
    F7(Keyboard.KEY_F7, "F7"),
    F8(Keyboard.KEY_F8, "F8"),
    F9(Keyboard.KEY_F9, "F9"),
    F10(Keyboard.KEY_F10, "F10"),
    F11(Keyboard.KEY_F11, "F11"),
    F12(Keyboard.KEY_F12, "F12"),
    F13(Keyboard.KEY_F13, "F13"),
    F14(Keyboard.KEY_F14, "F14"),
    F15(Keyboard.KEY_F15, "F15"),
    ONE(Keyboard.KEY_1, "1", "!", "one"),
    TWO(Keyboard.KEY_2, "2", "@", "two"),
    THREE(Keyboard.KEY_3, "3", "#", "three"),
    FOUR(Keyboard.KEY_4, "4", "$", "four"),
    FIVE(Keyboard.KEY_5, "5", "%", "five"),
    SIX(Keyboard.KEY_6, "6", "^", "six"),
    SEVEN(Keyboard.KEY_7, "7", "&", "seven"),
    EIGHT(Keyboard.KEY_8, "8", "*", "eight"),
    NINE(Keyboard.KEY_9, "9", "(", "nine"),
    ZERO(Keyboard.KEY_0, "0", ")", "zero"),
    MINUS(Keyboard.KEY_MINUS, "-", "_", "minus"),
    EQUALS_ADD(Keyboard.KEY_EQUALS, "=", "+", "plus", "equals"),
    INSERT(Keyboard.KEY_INSERT, "insert", "ins"),
    DEL(Keyboard.KEY_DELETE, "del", "delete"),
    HOME(Keyboard.KEY_HOME, "home"),
    ADD(Keyboard.KEY_ADD, "add"),
    PAGE_UP(Keyboard.KEY_PRIOR, "prior", "pageup"),
    PAGE_DOWN(Keyboard.KEY_NEXT, "next", "pagedown"),
    NUM_LOCK(Keyboard.KEY_NUMLOCK, "numlock", "numberlock"),
    SQBRACKET_LEFT(Keyboard.KEY_LBRACKET, "[", "{"),
    SQBRACKET_RIGHT(Keyboard.KEY_RBRACKET, "]", "}"),
    SEMICOLON(Keyboard.KEY_SEMICOLON, ";", ":");
    private static final Map<Integer, KeyFinder> keys = new HashMap<Integer, KeyFinder>();
    private static final Map<String, KeyFinder> lookup = new LinkedHashMap<String, KeyFinder>();
    private final int key;
    private final String keyName;
    private final String[] lookupKeys;
    static {
        for (KeyFinder type : EnumSet.allOf(KeyFinder.class)) {
            keys.put(type.key, type);
            for (String key : type.lookupKeys) {
                lookup.put(key, type);
            }
        }
    }

    KeyFinder(int key, String keyName, String lookupKey) {
        this.key = key;
        this.keyName = keyName;
        this.lookupKeys = new String[] { lookupKey };
    }

    KeyFinder(int key, String keyName, String... lookupKeys) {
        this.key = key;
        this.keyName = keyName;
        this.lookupKeys = lookupKeys;
    }

    public static KeyFinder fromKey(int key) {
        return keys.get(key);
    }

    public static String toKeyName(int key) {
        KeyFinder type = keys.get(key);
        if (type != null) {
            return type.getKeyName();
        } else {
            return "#" + key;
        }
    }

    public static KeyFinder lookup(String keyName) {
        return lookup(keyName, true);
    }

    public static KeyFinder lookup(String keyName, boolean fuzzy) {
        KeyFinder i = StringUtil.lookup(lookup, keyName, fuzzy);
        if(i != null)
            return i;
        else
            try {
                return fromKey(Integer.parseInt(keyName));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getKeyName() {
        return keyName;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is too long. Shorten your code to the shortest snippet that showcases the problem.

Comment: Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: Really, try to explain this in a more concise manner.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I would, but the problem is you need 99% of this to understand how the code works. It's quite complex.

Comment: @aerobit I find that unlikely.  It's almost certainly the case that you can pare this down to a dozen or so lines that demonstrate the problem.  (And in doing so, you may well solve the problem yourself)

Comment: No, we don't. For example, `ModuleBind` is completely useless for us

Comment: Ah, good point. I've pared down my code to hat I believe is the smallest needed to understand it.

Comment: Where can I find the `StringUtil` class?

Comment: @maba it was in the original post - check the edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stripped down your `KeyFinder` and tested together with the `StringUtil` and realize that you never ever use the `keyName` in your `lookup` map. So `a` is not there.

Here are some changes I did which might help you.

Change the `lookupKeys` to be a list instead of an array.

```
private final ArrayList<String> lookupKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Remove one of your constructors (it is obsolete since you have one with `varargs`)

```
KeyFinder(int key, String keyName, String lookupKey) // Remove
```

Change the other constructor and let `keyName` be included in the `lookupKeys`.

```
KeyFinder(int key, String keyName, String... lookupKeys) {
    this.key = key;
    this.keyName = keyName;
    this.lookupKeys.add(keyName);
    this.lookupKeys.addAll(Arrays.asList(lookupKeys));
}
```

It worked for me in some simple tests.

**NB**

I have not analyzed your code more than this. I don't know if you actually need the `keyName` but I leave that up to you. I just wanted the lookup to work.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you can't reduce the problem since your code is too convoluted (= it has too many dependencies).

Try to separate the code into independent bits and pieces and write unit tests for each of them. If the unit tests work, then you will know that any bug can only hide in the code that connects the different parts.

That said, my guess is that some method returns `null` and you wrote the code to silently fail for this case (i.e. instead of giving an error message "this shouldn't return null here", you just give up). Code like this is extremely unfriendly because any unusual condition will just make it fail silently without any clue whatsoever for the person trying to understand what is going on (you, in this case).

Comment: I wish this was the case, but the only lines that could possibly do that are already caught, as it'd return an exception if they were triggered. I only have one try/catch statement in the entire thing.

Comment: You don't understand. `if(key == null){return}` isn't error handling. It's error cover-up. `KeyFinder.lookup(keyChar);` should never return `null` but you don't check that. Your code just gives up (and hides the error instead of throwing an exception `"Unable to lookup key " + keyChar`

Comment: But I'm not covering up the errors. I'm checking if it's null, and if so, it should try a different method. lookup could definitely return null. My code hides that error, because it doesn't matter.

Either way, if I do `KeyFinder i = StringUtil.lookup(lookup, keyName, fuzzy);
      return i;`
I get 0 errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong that your code can't be stripped down - and if you did, you'd have found the error yourself.

[Here's an ideone snippet](http://ideone.com/fYVeH) that illustrates the core of your failed lookup.  Notice that the first of your key characters doesn't appear in the lookup map - because it's the `keyName` and not a `lookupKey`.

[Here's a modified snippet](http://ideone.com/GRCdp) where the name also appears as a lookup key.  Unsurprisingly, the lookup succeeds.

In fact, having a `keyName` field seems to be pointless since it's never used (and `toString()` would be a more appropriate to get the "name" of the enum constant).  So [this variant](http://ideone.com/mAh2y) is probably the better one.

---

Your problem was *nothing* to do with letters vs symbols; it was simply that the first quoted symbol wouldn't work (so a lookup on a capital letter would have worked).  Equally it didn't require 99% to understand how the code worked, it was simply an issue of populating the static map incorrectly.

Please try to be less blinkered and more proactive in future.

Comment: Gah, thanks. I feel really stupid now, I wasn't realizing the fact that my own code wasn't working like that.
Thanks for the informative answer :)